# How Can I Add An Include Path in GCC C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I can add include paths in Visual Studio easily but I couldn't find a way to do it in GCC? Any helps please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-I` command-line argument:

```
gcc -Ipath
```

Comment: The flag and and path needs to be combined?

Comment: Yes. You can find a full command line reference here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to accept the answer because of the documentation link.

Answer (score 4):

`gcc` is a command-line program, the flag for `includes` is `-I`

```
gcc -IC:\AdditionalIncludeDirectory <other-flags>
```

Comment: I also need a Linux solution. I think I need to do `gcc -I/include/path`?

Comment: Yes it is the same flag in Linux

Comment: How can I add one or multiple include directories?

Comment: Simply add several `-I` switches

Answer (score 1):

There are many options related to the search of the include files. The most common used is -I*path*

[image]

Comment: please do not post images.  Rather, copypaste the actual text into your answer

Comment: + preferably also with a relevant link to the docs

Comment: I agree with user3629249 and costaparas but anyways I'll just upvote.